# Reading file saving as hex c

Tags: c, binary, hex, fread

Using fread (programming in c) to read a .txt or a .bin with only binary results in `fread(buffer,1,count,pFile)` where;

`char *buffer`

`long count`

and `pFile` is a pointer to the file. Hence if `stream` is/contains 11110000 then `count=8`, this will result in array with 8 elements. Each element will by of type `char` and hence contain 8 bits. How would one read a .txt or .bin file such that the 8 bits are represented using 1 array entry, preferably as a hex value (so in this case `buffer[0]={0xF0}`)?

Comment: This seems like an assignment. Try it by yourself first, then show us what are you done and we may be able to help you.

Comment: in other words provide a [mcve]

Comment: Post the relevant part of your attempt, so that we can help you understanding how to progress. Just another question: does the input file contain just text representing binary numbers in some sort of big endian style (most significant bits come first)? In that case, are we sure that the file contains a multiple of 8 characters?